# Android Game Development, Low FPS on tablet/high FPS on phones

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

i nearly finished an android game that i started to develop a little time ago.
Actually, it worked fine on my test device (as i am an independant game developper, i use my personnal phone to test) which is a galaxy S2. I tried to optimize it correctly by following google's best practice and, obviously, stackoverflow.
At the moment, i get an average 60~70fps on my galaxy s2.
When I decided to test it on tablet (a manta 1008MID pro, not very famous), i noticed some lag, and i get only ~24 FPS. I don't understand, because sims to have a better hardware that my old phone.

The current method used for drawing is Android Canvas and bitmap. I followed KiloBolt tutorials : http://www.kilobolt.com/unit-4-android-game-development.html

The method user sims to be to scale the main Bitmap to screen size.

Help me please, I don't understand why the fps are so low on my tablet !

(sorry for bad english, I'm french)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if hardware acceleration is used on your tablet.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Hi thank you for your response.
I already activated hardware acceleration :/